# Где находится RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android

Автор книги, которую сейчас изучаю, предлагает в Android Studio перетащить на панель Preview компонент RelativeLayout.

У меня установлен Android Studio 3.6.2.  Но в нём нет такого layout. Есть другие варианты: ConstreintLayout, FrameLayout и др. То ли RelativeLayout переименовали, то ли заменили. Я пока в этом плохо разбираюсь.

Подскажите, чем заменить RelativeLayout (или где найти) для того, чтобы я смог выполнить задачу описанную в книге?

Comment: в legacy он находится, и не зря он там, он медленный и уже устарел, вместо него лучше использовать ConstraintLayout

Comment: Теперь я обнаружил, что ConstraintLayout  из палитры Component Tree нельзя удалить. Это у меня глюк или так и должно быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить такой вид layout можно так же и вручную, если у вас по какой-то причине он отсутствует. Для этого нужно перейти в текстовое или смешанное представление файла xml и добавить layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</RelativeLayout>
```

либо если это будет родительский layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Так же советую воспользоваться поиском по виджетам при выборе palette в preview:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите такой layout есть и никуда не пропал) Как один из вариантов - вы не там ищете :)